# How do I set the number of nodes visible on the front page?

Tags: drupal

How do I set the number of nodes visible on the front page?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of nodes on the home page is in (/admin/config/system/site-information)

Answer (score 3):

The number of nodes on the home page is configurable (/admin/config/system/site-information).

Comment: Note that you can also set your hoome page to some other page that you specify at `http://yourdrupalpath/admin/config/system/site-information`

Answer (score 3):

If you are not using a view as front page, and you are using Drupal 7, then the number of nodes visible in the front page is set in admin/config/system/site-information.

[image: screenshot]

If you are using the "Front page" view as front page, in addition to the previous setting, there is a setting on admin/structure/views/view/frontpage/edit for that view, which changes the number of nodes shown in a single page of the pager.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]